# su -session-command error

Tags: linux, fedora, su, objectdb

i have a very simple and annoying problem, i'm trying to start my database as a specific user, but **su --session-comman**d fail to me!

```
##############################

#!/bin/bash

objectdb-start.sh

OBJECTDB_HOME=/opt/java-tools/objectdb-2.3.0_04
JAVA_USER=javauser

CMD="su --session-command=\"${OBJECTDB_HOME}/bin/objectdb.sh start\" ${JAVA_USER}"

echo $CMD
$CMD

##############################
```

Then a got this error:

```
[root@Taturana bin]# ./objectdb-start.sh
su --session-command="/opt/java-tools/objectdb-2.3.0_04/bin/objectdb.sh start" javauser
su: user start" does not exist
```

Any idea?

PS: i'm using Fedora 15

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` will have no effect unless it is the __very first thing__ in your script file.

Answer (score 2):

The escaped double quotes are causing you trouble. They do not function on the command line as you obviously expect them to. Therefore the shell sees the space and interprets `start"` as the second argument to `su`, specifying the username.

Is echoing the command line on the console really important? You'd probably be better off with something like this:

```
su --session-command="${OBJECTDB_HOME}/bin/objectdb.sh start" $JAVA_USER
```

Or use `sudo` instead:

```
sudo -u $JAVA_USER $OBJECTDB_HOME/bin/objectdb.sh start
```

Comment: echo is just to see what is the command like and sudo cannot be used cause it requires a tty, and i going to add this script to systemd

Comment: you're right, i changed the quotes for to use: `` and worked fine.